# To find customer who have purchased only one time in magento

Tags: magento

I know how to get order details of customer in magento with the following code

```
$salesModel=Mage::getModel("sales/order");
$salesCollection = $salesModel->getCollection()
                  ->setOrder('increment_id','DESC');
```

But i need to display the customer details who have purchased only one time. I don't know how to resolve it. If anybody know, please save me guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go with the query, bellow query will help you,

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_id HAVING COUNT(customer_id) = 1
```

or This can be used,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $user){
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$user->getId());
    if($orders->getSize() == 1){
        echo $user->getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hiren Soni, But i want to get from the collection, i know this also can done by you

Comment: @DRAJI I have update my answer that can help you... let me know if it works for you. or accept this answer so it can be use full to other in future.

Comment: Thank you somuch Hiren Soni. now it works well, i think this is 1st answer to this question in both stackoverflow and magento commerece.Because i spent more time to get an answer to this Question. But there is no place having. thanks once again!